# why stripe confirm method is not confirming the payment or updating the status?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have created the `paymentIntent` using the stripe `create` method and implements the 3d security to validate the payment but in the status of the paymentIntent is `"status": "requires_action",` so i have implemented the stripe `confirm` method to confirm the payment and change the status is equal to `succeeded`. but it is not confirming the payment. why?

*here is confirm method stuff*

```
let paymentIntent = req.query.payment_intent;

let retrieve = await stripe.paymentIntents
        .retrieve(paymentIntent)
        .then((response) => {
          return response;
        });

      if (
        typeof retrieve != "undefined" &&
        retrieve.status == "requires_confirmation"
      ) {
        let confirmPayment = await stripe.paymentIntents
          .confirm(paymentIntent, { payment_method: "pm_card_visa" })
          .then((response) => {
            return res.send(response);
          });
       }
```

while hitting the API gets the response that the status remains `requires_action` instead of `succeeded` also in the stripe dashboard payment remains incomplete.

Comment: i was fixed the problem by commenting `{ payment_method: "pm_card_visa" }`.

Answer (score 0):

When a PaymentIntent has a status of `requires_action`, it means that the customer needs to complete additional authentication steps (like 3D Secure) for the payment to be confirmed. You should handle the action by using Stripe.js or the mobile SDKs on your front-end to open a pop-up or an in-app screen for the customer to complete the authentication.

You can use the Stripe JS function [handleNextAction](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/handle_next_action).

For a more in-depth understanding, I suggest reviewing the Stripe documentation on [3D Secure authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure).